# Recycler view items disappear when I scroll my recycler view to top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The problem is that when I scroll up my recycler view some items gets disappear

1. Here is MyAdapter Code of RecyclerView

   ```
   class MessageAdapter:androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter<MessageEntity,MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>(MessageDiffCallBack()){
       inner class MessageViewHolder(val view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
       class MessageDiffCallBack:DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MessageEntity>(){
           override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MessageEntity, newItem: MessageEntity): Boolean {
               return oldItem.timeStamp==newItem.timeStamp
           }

           override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MessageEntity, newItem: MessageEntity): Boolean {
               return oldItem==newItem
           }

       }

       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder {
          val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.chat_item,parent,false)
          return MessageViewHolder(view)
       }

       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
          val messageEntity=getItem(position)
           val ourTextView=holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ourUserMessage)
           val otherTextView=holder.view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.otherUserMessage)
           val ourCardView=holder.view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.ourCardView)
           val otherCardView=holder.view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.otherCardView)
           if(messageEntity.senderId==FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid){
               otherCardView.visibility=View.GONE
               ourTextView.text=messageEntity.message
           }
           else{
               ourCardView.visibility=View.GONE
               otherTextView.text=messageEntity.message
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Can anyone help me in this problem

Comment: Please, mark my answer as right if it helped you.

Comment: this solution didnot work for me